# How to re-use a component in React and Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, code-reuse

Maybe I didn't get the concepts right. I usually see in the examples, a `Counter` class and then the `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`, and then using `connect` to create the "Higher Order Component" and export it as the default.

I wonder how do we re-use this `Counter` component?

For example:

1. If we need two instances of `Counter` on the same page
2. If we need `Counter` on page 2, and it should be related to another redux state (not the one we defined in that original file)

And then it dawns on me: it seems in practice, we actually may just define `Counter.js` without all those `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps`, and `connect`, and then we would create `IceCreamCounter.js` that first `import Counter` (the plain counter) and does all the `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps`, and `connect` to make it into one HOC and export it?

And then if the same page need another counter, then we use `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps`, and `connect` in, for example, `DrinkCounter.js` and do the appropriate mappings to the redux store.

Likewise, if it is the "To Go Order" page, and we need a counter for the number of spoons needed, then we actually would have `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps`, and `connect` and create a `SpoonCounter.js`:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import Counter from './Counter';  // the plain counter component

const mapStateToProps = ...;
const mapDispatchToProps = ...;

const SpoonCounter = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Counter);
export default SpoonCounter;
```

and that's how we achieve component re-use?

I wonder why I didn't see how this is done before... is it actually explained in some official docs or blogs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an official doc, per se, but from a fairly "official" source. The container component pattern. This is the post that turned me on to the pattern.

https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

Here you've stumbled upon it. The "dumb" counter component is the presentation component, the *visual* aspect, the UI, whereas, in your case, the `react-redux` `connect` HOC returns the "smart" component, it connects tangible data, like your app state, to the presentation component.

Comment: But that article mentioned "Update from 2019: I wrote this article a long time ago and my views have since evolved. In particular, I don’t suggest splitting your components like this anymore. If you find it natural in your codebase, this pattern can be handy. But I’ve seen it enforced without any necessity and with almost dogmatic fervor far too many times. The main reason I found it useful was because it let me separate complex stateful logic from other aspects of the component. Hooks let me do the same thing without an arbitrary division" So should we go north or west now?

Comment: But I think we could still have a component that does `cSpoons = useSelector(state => state.countOfSpoons)` and then render a `<Count count={cSpoons}>` so as to reuse `Count` and we have to pass down the dispatch to alter it too

Comment: @StefanieGauss Sure? Not really clear if you're asking a question or just making a statement. The `useSelector` hook essentially replaces the `mapStateToProps` function used by the `connect` Higher Order Component. It seems in your example that `Count` would still be a "presentational" component that is passed a `count` prop to display.

Comment: I am both making a statement and trying to get some verification. I think I found about React / Redux is that I do not see much talk at all about code reuse. If it is 3 counters, people on their Discord mention just write the counter 3 times, or use an array of size 3 in Redux and the Counter taking each of those array element... it is so tightly coupled

Comment: @StefanieGauss Well, if it is 3 instances of the same counter component, then state/UI are likely be coupled internally, but if you need 3 separate counters, each with their own state, then you can move the state selectors outside the counter component and pass the state into the reusable component, or use *some* alternative like assigning an `id` and each counter registers itself in state in order to create *its* state. The code reuse with react/redux is in reusable, unconnected presentational components, or in the state selectors functions that can be shared between connected components.